# Why isn't my passport middleware function working correctly?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, middleware

I am new to web development, and am working on setting up user authentication with Passport.js for a Node.js app. Everything about the user authentication works perfectly, except for the image I am trying to load on the login form. I know that the image's failure to load is somehow tied to my middleware function, because when I remove the middleware function by commenting out the line:
`app.use(checkAuthenticated);`, the image loads correctly, and everything is good. This is my middleware function:

```
    function checkAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
      if (req.isAuthenticated() || req.path.includes('login')) {
        return next()
      }
        res.redirect('/login')
        return;
    }
```

I also assumed that this type of middleware function to check Authentication with Passport.js would be quite common, so I would appreciate any feedback whatsoever about what the best thing to do for such a middleware function is. I feel like my implementation was somewhat improper, the "or path.includes('login')" bit feels very inelegant, but it is the only thing I could think of that made the function work, without it getting trapped in an infinite loop(because upon first visit, the user wouldn't be authenticated, and each redirect would continue to get redirected). Thank you for any help you may provide, and please let me know if there is anything I can do to clarify anything.

Edit:
I also wanted to add, in case this is of any help, how the login file is being served, and how the image is being loaded into the login file. For the command to serve the login file, I have:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'login-page.html'));
});
```

And for the login file's link to the image, I have just the classic:
`<img src="path to the image">`

Answer (score 0):

I found out what mistake I made, just going to leave the question and answer here in case anyone had a similar issue.
So the middleware function is called every time anything gets served, including the images/css that are tied to the html file. When my login.html file was served, it had to have the css and image go through the middleware function before also being served. The somewhat jank solution I had meant that any request that included the word login would go through, and my css file was named login.css, so it went through, but my image was named something that didn't include the word login, so it was blocked for non-authenticated users(all users on the login page would not be authenticated). I am still open to any opinions from web developers about more elegant solutions though.